# Freemarker and webflux errors

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

When i use freemarker in webflux app i'm always get one exception: cannot resolve view with name '';

My FreemarkerConfig:

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths("classpath:/src/main/resources/templates");
    return configurer;
}
```

ViewResolver:

```
@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.freeMarker().suffix(".ftl");
}
```

classpath: 
[my classpatg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVeyo.png)

stacktrace: 
[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHeea.png)

mainrouter:

```
@Configuration
public class MainRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(MainHandler mainHandler){

        RequestPredicate get = RequestPredicates.GET("/news");

        return RouterFunctions.route(get, mainHandler::news);
    }
}
```

mainhandler:

```
@Component
public class MainHandler {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> news(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

        Mono<? extends Principal> principal = serverRequest.principal();

        return principal.flatMap(p -> {

            logger.info(p.getName());

            return userService.findByUserName(p.getName()).flatMap(user -> {
                return ServerResponse.ok().render("news", Map.of("currentUser", user, "messages", userService.findMessages(user)))
                        .onErrorResume(error->{
                    logger.info(error.getLocalizedMessage());
                    return ServerResponse.badRequest().build();
                });
            });

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that should be `"classpath:/templates"` The `/src/main/resources/` part is gone when you build the project, like an output `jar` will have the `templates` directory directly under the archive root directory.